# XSLT-1.0: How to insert an element at a specific position with respect to the parent element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to find out the position of a child element with respect to its parent.
I have the following input XML:

```
<Begin>
    <tag1>g</tag1>
    <tag2>b</tag2>
    <tag3>c</tag3>
    <tag5>e</tag5>
</Begin>
```

I need to know the position of `<tag3>` with respect to `<Begin>`, i.e. 3

Can this be done in XSLT?
My current XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Begin[count(tag4)=0]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Need to find the position of /Begin/tag3" here -->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to find the position of `<tag3>` in the input XML
and **insert `<tag4>` exactly after `<tag3>` using the position**.

So my question is:
How can I insert an element `<tag4>` at the position between `<tag3>` and `<tag5>`?
This is my intent!

Comment: Currently you do not have a `<tag4>` in your XML...

Comment: exactly.. in the input tag4 is not present. But i want it to be in my output in an exact position

Comment: Why check the position? Just change your match to `Begin[not(tag4)]/tag3` and then output both `tag3` and the new `tag4`.

Comment: Hi @DanielHaley- :) that actually works. But just curious.. how can we find the positon of tag3 w.r.t Begin?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to insert a new element sorted alphabetically is to  use `<xsl:sort>` in the *identity template* like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
      <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This modification does copy all elements sorted alphabetically by the local-name/tag-name/element-name.

Comment: coincidentally the tags here are tag1, tag2, etc. What if my xml looks like-

<def>123</def><abc>343</abc>

and I want to insert <ghi> after <def>. The above solution won't work

Comment: OK, this is another question - please provide an [mcve].

Comment: I have already written "IN A SPECIFIC POSITION". I never wrote alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the position of the child using either `xsl:number`, or `count(preceding-sibling::*)`.

But that doesn't help you with the next part of the problem: `insert <tag4> exactly after <tag3> using the position`. In XSLT you always add new data to the current writing position in the result tree, you can't add it in a specific position. So I think we need to know what you actually want to achieve, rather than your proposed method of achieving it.

Comment: And why not the `position()` function?

Comment: Because explaining to people that position() sometimes gives you the position of an element among its siblings, and sometimes doesn't, depending on the context, gets complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know the position of a node in order to insert another node after (or before) it. In your given example, you can use:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag3">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <tag4>d</tag4>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Begin>
    <tag1>g</tag1>
    <tag2>b</tag2>
    <tag3>c</tag3>
    <tag4>d</tag4>
    <tag5>e</tag5>
</Begin>
```

Of course, if there is no `tag3` element in the provided input, then nothing will happen. And if there are several, the new element will be inserted after each one.

Comment: I agree to your solution. the best one was given by @DanielHaley in the comments. Anyways, I am just curious to know how do i find out the exact position of an element? not sure how count(preceding-sibling::*) will help

Comment: As I said in a comment, you can use the `position()` function. The exact answer depends on *why* you need this. For example, you could simply use `<xsl:template match="item[3]">` to match an item that's third in the current node list.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in my comment, and very similar to @michael.hor257k's answer, instead of checking the position, just change your match to `Begin[not(tag4)]/tag3` and then output both `tag3` and the new `tag4`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Begin[not(tag4)]/tag3">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <tag4>d</tag4>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Hi @DanielHaley- :) that actually works. But just curious.. how can we
>   find the positon of tag3 w.r.t Begin?

If you were using XSLT 2.0, you could just use `<xsl:number select="tag3" count="*"/>` (1.0 doesn't allow the `select` element on xsl:number).

In 1.0, you can use a moded template that uses either `xsl:number` or `count(preceding-sibling::*)` (as suggested by @michael-kay)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Begin[not(tag4)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Need to find the position of /Begin/tag3" here -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tag3" mode="getPos"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="getPos">
    <xsl:number count="*"/>
    <!-- alternative to xsl:number:
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
    -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output would be:

```
<Begin>3</Begin>
```