# XSLT 1.0 How to update or insert an element after an optional element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is similar to this question: [XSLT-1.0: How to insert an element at a specific position with respect to the parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43359395/13087), but the answer there doesn't cover the case where `tag3` is missing in the input XML

I want to insert or update a tag (say tag4) in the an XML document that looks like the following, except that tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 and tag5 are all optional.

```
<Begin>
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag2 value="b" />
    <tag3 value="c" />
    <tag4 value="d" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

I.e. the following are sample inputs and outputs

Input:

```
<Begin>
</Begin>
```

Output:

```
<Begin>
    <tag4 value="updated" />
</Begin>
```

Input:

```
<Begin>
    <tag4 value="d" />
</Begin>
```

Output:

```
<Begin>
    <tag4 value="updated" />
</Begin>
```

Input:

```
<Begin>
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

Output:

```
<Begin>
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag4 value="updated" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

Input:

```
<Begin>
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag2 value="b" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

Output:

```
<Begin>
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag2 value="b" />
    <tag4 value="updated" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

Input:

```
<Begin>
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag2 value="b" />
    <tag3 value="c" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

Output:

```
<Begin>
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag2 value="b" />
    <tag3 value="c" />
    <tag4 value="updated" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

**UPDATE**

I also want to be able to preserve any attributes that may already be present on the Begin or tag4 element, e.g.:

Input:

```
<Begin someAttribute="someValue">
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag2 value="b" />
    <tag3 value="c" />
    <tag4 value="d" someOtherAttribute="someOtherValue" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

Output:

```
<Begin someAttribute="someValue">
    <tag1 value="a" />
    <tag2 value="b" />
    <tag3 value="c" />
    <tag4 value="updated" someOtherAttribute="someOtherValue" />
    <tag5 value="e" />
</Begin>
```

Comment: Do you know the names of the attributes "that may already be present" on the tag4 element?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - no I don't, they are subject to change.  So I essentially want to copy the tag4 element, then add/update my "value" attribute if the tag4 element is  present, or create it if not.

Comment: Then either copy all of `tag4`'s attributes and **then** override the `value` attribute, or copy all its attributes except `value`. For the `Begin` element, you can simply copy all its attributes before any of its children (or together with the first batch of its children)..

Comment: @michael.hor257k - yes, that's essentially what I expect to do.  Michael Kay has given me most of what I need and I'm sure I'll be able to work out the rest on my own (unless he's kind enough to update his answer!).  Once I've done this I'll accept his answer.

Comment: My suggestions are on top of the answer given by Dr. Kay. I would have given you the same answer (minus the typo on line1, hopefully). Here's an example of implementation of the 2nd option I mentioned: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvV

Comment: @michael.hor257k - thanks for the additional info in your xsltfiddle, which helped me remember a bit more of what I used to know about xslt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="Begin">
  <Begin>
    <xsl:copy-of select="tag1 | tag2 | tag3"/>
    <tag4 value="updated"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="tag5"/>
  </Begin>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 That's nearly what I need and I may be able to work out the rest for myself.  What I didn't mention (hoping to keep the sample as simple as possible) was that I want to preserve any attributes that already may be present on any of the tags Begin or tag4. I'll update one of the samples to show what I mean.

Comment: Those problems are quite independent of the question you raised, so if you can't work them out for yourself, raise a new question. (There's nothing difficult there, if you're having problems, it suggests you really ought to do some more reading.)

Comment: You're absolutely right that I should be able to work the rest out for myself.  I see from your bio that you're the author of the XSLT Programmers Reference, an excellent book which I read about 17 years ago, the last time I used XSLT until very recently.  I should probably buy a copy and reread it.  Also saw that you may have worked at ICL at the same time I did (remember System 25?)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...  Trace it through in a debugger to help you figure it out, if needed.

```
    <xsl:template match="Begin">
      <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Apply any attributes for Begin.  -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

        <!-- Output the tag* nodes before tag4. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tag1|tag2|tag3"/>

        <xsl:choose>
          <!-- Is there already a tag4? -->
          <xsl:when test="tag4">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tag4"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Create tag4 -->
            <tag4 value="updated"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <!-- Output the tag* nodes after tag4. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tag5"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag4">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">d</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="someOtherAttribute">someOtherValue</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This looks like a good approach, I'll experiment with it.  Surprised to see it downvoted without even the courtesy of a comment, so I'll cancel that out with an upvote :)